# What is a Nokia FAID?

Tags: mobile

Nokia is a mobile phone brand, but what is an FAID? I tried searching but no definition came up. I'm guessing it's a security feature checked by the hardware in order to function properly.

Comment: Some context of the term would definitely be helpful. There are just too many 4 letter abbreviations around.

Comment: Hi oakad, I searched more and found out it means Flash Authority ID. Anyway, I think Nokia is enough of a context.

Comment: Hi rev1.0 and all. Knowing the answer below, is this post still off-topic? Just to be clear, the checksum is not considered an electronic device right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brought it into context with firmware updating Nokia phones and came up with [this](http://www.unlockme.co.uk/dct3flashing.html):

The reference states that when the firmware has been altered this happens:

> Your phone should power on at this point but it will keep on restarting and will not receive a signal.

And further explains why and how to solve it:

> [...] when you alter the flash memory within your phone there are certain security checksums that need to be updated. The checksum that we need to update is called the FAID (Flash Authority ID) [...] it is quite a simple process!